# Recursive method does not work in android

Tags: java, android, loops, recursion

I am creating a quiz app and i want to use a recursive function to loop through the questions, choices and answers string arrays. If the button with the correct answer is selected then the method should be called again with different values using recursion, but this does not happen. I hope that my code is not too messy since I am a beginner.

Here's my code:

```
public class Info extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    String [] questionsIT = {
            "When did Windows 10 appear?",
            "When did the first iPhone appear?",
            "Who presented the iPhone 4?",
            "What's the most widely used browser in the world?",
            "Which language is Windows written in?",
            "WHich country did the inventor of PHP language come from?",
            "How many cores does a quad-core processor have?",
            "Which company owns XBOX?",
            "Which company owns PlayStation?",
            "In which american state are the Google headquarters located?"
    };

    String [][] choicesIT = {
            {"1989", "2015", "2002", "2012"},
            {"1999", "2006", "2008", "2007"},
            {"Steve Jobs", "Tim Cook", "Bill Gates", "Steve Wozniak"},
            {"Microsoft Edge", "Internet Explorer", "Google Chrome", "Mozilla Firefox"},
            {"C++", "Pascal", "Java", "Perl"},
            {"Romania", "UK", "Greenland", "Germany"},
            {"2 cores", "4 cores", "6 cores", "8 cores"},
            {"Google", "Sony", "Samsung", "Microsoft"},
            {"Microsoft", "Sony", "Apple", "Nokia"},
            {"New York", "Texas", "Ohio", "California"}
    };

    String [] answersIT = {
            "2015",
            "2007",
            "Steve Jobs",
            "Google Chrome",
            "C++",
            "Greenland",
            "4 cores",
            "Microsoft",
            "Sony",
            "California"
    };

    int[] picsID = {R.drawable.win10, R.drawable.iphone1, R.drawable.apple};

    RelativeLayout rlinfo = findViewById(R.id.rlinfo);
    final TextView intrbinfo = findViewById(R.id.intrbinfo);
    int score = 0;
    int i = 0;
    intrbinfo.setText("");

    Something(questionsIT, choicesIT, answersIT, i, score,intrbinfo);

}

public int Something(String[] q, String [][]ch, String[] a, int x, int scor, TextView textView)
{
    x = 0;
    scor = 0;
    int y = 0;
    RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    RadioButton[] chooses = {findViewById(R.id.choose1), findViewById(R.id.choose2), findViewById(R.id.choose3), findViewById(R.id.choose4)};
    textView.setText(q[x]);
    chooses[0].setText(ch[x][0]);
    chooses[1].setText(ch[x][1]);
    chooses[2].setText(ch[x][2]);
    chooses[3].setText(ch[x][3]);
    if (chooses[0].isChecked() && chooses[0].equals(a[x]))
    {
        scor++; x++;
        Something(q,ch,a, x,scor, textView);}
    if(y == 10){
        return 0; //Here the loop stops cause there are no more questions
    }

    if (chooses[1].isChecked() && chooses[1].equals(a[x]))
    {
        scor++; x++;
        Something(q,ch,a, x,scor, textView);}
    if(y == 10){
        return 0;
    }

    if (chooses[2].isChecked() && chooses[2].equals(a[x]))
    {
        scor++; x++;
        Something(q,ch,a, x,scor, textView);}
    if(y == 10){
        return 0;
    }

    if (chooses[3].isChecked() && chooses[3].equals(a[x]))
    {
        scor++; x++;
        Something(q,ch,a, x,scor, textView);}
    if(y == 10){
        return 0;
    }

    return y;
}
}
```

Comment: Recursion should only really be used for passing a single value and manipulating it. You should use for loops instead.

Comment: The method might not be getting called because all the if conditions are to be false. Have you checked the flow using a debugger?

Comment: The code has to keep track of 3 different, but related arrays which could be causing some of the problems.  Consider creating a class such as `Question`, which has an `Answer[] possibleAnswers`, where `Answer` has an `boolean accepted` (so one of the `possibleAnswers` is true).  Then a single `Question[] questions` instead of 3 different arrays.